# How to overwrite an Entity in Symfony2 bundle

Tags: php, bundle, symfony

I'm using **FOSUserBundle** for **Symfony2**, and I need to be able to register a user **without validating if the email is Unique**, I just need a valid email so **many users can have the same email** ( I know this is weird, but I need it).

I have an entity "User" in a bundle that **extends FOSUserBundle**, is it possible to **overwrite the column definition** of emailCanonical to eliminate the unique parameter and remove the validation from the FormType?

I'm using Annotation for mapping my Entities and YML for validation of my forms.

Answer (score 4):

I had a [similar issue](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/338) few weeks ago. The only solution is to extend model instead of entity:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser
```

The downside is that you have to also copy everything from FOS User entity to your User entity. On the other hand, you can adjust the functionality to your needs.

Comment: The FOS User Entity contains nothing more than: `abstract class User extends AbstractUser
{
}`

Do you mean _The downside is that you have to also copy everything from FOS User Model to your User Model, and then have your Entity extend your new User Model_?

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question at first. I had situation where I needed to create bit more custom Entity. In my own bundle, I created new User entity that extended `Model\User` from FOSUserBundle and overridden all methods and variables from it. Then I created new validation rules (via annotations in the same entity) that belonged to different validation group (as you described in your answer). My original question is here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/338. It's not really the same issue as you asked, but it could help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found something, it's partially a **work around**, not viable solution.

The problem is divided in two parts: the form and the model.

**For the form:**
To overwrite the unique constraint of FOSUserBundle Registration Form you can modify the registration validations groups in the app/config/config.yml:

```
fos_user:
  registration:
    validation_groups: [YourValidationGroup]
```

**For the model:**
I haven't found a good solution without overwriting all the model. Doctrine2 explicitly tells that you can't overwrite a property of a Mapped Class. So I did a migration that drop the unique constraint index with DoctrineMigrationBundle... I'm not proud of this solution but it works and it let me save a duplicate email.

If you have better solution for the model don't hesitate!