# How to modify FOSUserBundle unique validator?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to modify the way FOSUSerBundle validates the username/email when the user registers, because I need to check if the user was previously registered, but he has unsubscribed, through status flag in the entity. I think the best way is check if email is previously on the database, excluding those who the flag `unsubscribed` is set to true, but how I do this?

So, I see how validates with `UniqueValidator` class, but I don't understand how it works. It would be great if anyone could explain it too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UniqueValidator` calls [validateUnique](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Entity/UserManager.php#L108) method of `UserManager` class. You can extend the class and modify the function to check user

```
$this->findUserByEmail($user->getEmail());
```

**Edit**

For second question, you have to override `UpdateUser` method of the `UserManager` class.

```
/**
 * Updates a user.
 *
 * @param UserInterface $user
 * @param Boolean $andFlush Whether to flush the changes (default true)
 */
public function updateUser(UserInterface $user, $andFlush = true)
{
    $existsUser = $this->findUserByEmail($user->getEmail()); 
    $this->updateCanonicalFields($user);
    $this->updatePassword($user);

    if($existsUser && null === $user->getId()){
        $user->setId($existsUser->getId());
        $this->em->merge($user);
    } else{
        $this->em->persist($user);
    }

    if ($andFlush) {
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, but how I should proceed to extend the class? I created a custom  `UserManager` class, but I don't know to override the original FOS `UserManager` class. I saved it to my bundle, linked to the original class as `use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\UserManger as BaseUserManager`, but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Check second solution of [this](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/logging_by_username_or_email.md) doc entry.

Comment: by the way, of course, I'm getting an `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation:` error... how I could redefine the email field to allow duplicate entries?

Comment: nevermind - [already asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7476486/how-to-overwrite-an-entity-in-symfony2-bundle)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see the point of override in that way the function that updates the user. Why it should solve the problem with duplicated entries in a unique-field entity mapping? Maybe I didn't explain the issue very well... I need to _allow_ to create duplicate entries, ie, when user unsubscribe and then wants to subscribe again, should be 2 entries, with the same email... I know it sounds weird, but its a client-demand issue :( thanks!